# Dockerize Laravel API and NextJS 14 application

Tags: laravel, docker, next.js, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize my Laravel API and my NextJS 14 application. WhenI was running my applications in development using `php artisan serve` and `npm run dev` my application was running fine. I used the `docker-compose up --build -d` to run my container. My applications are reachable in the localhost:3000 and localhost:8000 as they supposed to, but when i try to make a request from my frontend to my backend I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
the requested resource.
```

Here is my config/cors.php:

```
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
/api
    - Dockerfile
    - docker-compose.yml
/webapp
    - Dockerfile
```

This is the Dockerfile in my API directory root:

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zip unzip git
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . .

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

This is the Dockerfile in my webapp directory root:

```
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml in my API directory root:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - uploads:/var/www/html/storage/app/public
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db

  webapp:
    build:
      context: ../webapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1

volumes:
  db_data:
  uploads:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` isn't the same, when it comes to CORS.

Your frontend should contact `localhost` backend when you're accessing the frontend on `localhost`.

Comment: I changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost and now i get this:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But my cors.php should allow requests from any origin.